# How to Rotate GameObjects keeping relative positions to another GameObject are fixed

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a GameObject(Golfer) and Golfball GameObjects.

I can spin the Golfer on swiping the screen.

```c#
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    f_difX = 0.0f;
}
else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    f_difX = Mathf.Abs(f_lastX - Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X"));

    if (f_lastX < Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X"))
    {
        i_direction = -1;
        m_CurrentObj.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -f_difX);

    }

    if (f_lastX > Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X"))
    {
        i_direction = 1;
        m_CurrentObj.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, f_difX);

    }

    f_lastX = -Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
}
```

With this code, the Golfer spin as shown in the following two images.

[image]

[image]

I need to rotate the Golfballs by keeping their relative positions to the Golfer are fixed.

I think I need to use RotateAround.

How can I rotated Golfballs with respect to the Golfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put golfball inside an empty gameobject that have the same pivot as the player, then rotate that gameobject instead. The golf ball will keep its localPosition and end up being rotated around the player.